# How to indent output of multiline-outputs such as summary, using print or cat, and keep columns aligned?

Tags: r, printing, indentation, cat, summary

The question probably generalizes to printing any type of multiline output, and keeping the columns aligned. My actual issue concerns the output of `summary.default`.

I'm trying to add indentation of a multiple of two to `cat` output of the `summary.default` function. I've made some attempts using `cat` and `print`, also consulting some related answers, but they all fail so far.

```
f <- function(x) {
  s <- summary.default(x)
  liner <- Reduce(paste0, rep("-", 70))
  cat("\n", liner, "\n")  ## ATT 1. -------------------------------
  cat("\n", "foo first attempt", "\n")
  cat("\n--|\n")
  
  print(round(s, 3))  #
  
  cat("\n----|\n")
  cat("\n    *additional information\n")
  cat("\n", liner, "\n")  ## ATT 2. -------------------------------
  cat("\n", "foo second attempt", "\n")
  cat("\n--|\n")
  
  print(unname(as.data.frame(cbind("   ", t(attr(s, "names"))))), row.names=F)  #
  print(unname(as.data.frame(cbind(" ", t(round(unclass(s), 3))))), row.names=F)  #
  
  cat("\n----|\n")
  cat("\n    *additional information\n")
  cat("\n", liner, "\n")  ## ATT 3. -------------------------------
  cat("\n", "foo third attempt", "\n")
  cat("\n--|\n")
  cat("\n  ", attr(s, "names"), "\n")
  
  cat("\n  ", round(s, 3), "\n")  #
  
  cat("\n----|\n")
  cat("\n    *additional information\n")
}
```

```
> x <- rnorm(100)
> f(x)

---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 foo first attempt 

--|
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -2.069  -0.654  -0.092  -0.075   0.696   1.997 

----|

    *additional information

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 foo second attempt 

--|
                                          
     Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
                                          
   -2.069 -0.654 -0.092 -0.075 0.696 1.997

----|

    *additional information

 ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 

 foo third attempt 

--|

   Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd Qu. Max. 

   -2.069 -0.654 -0.092 -0.075 0.696 1.997 

----|

    *additional information
```

The `---|` symbolize the required indentation. *First attempt* does not have any indentation. *Second attempt* is better, but there's additional space between the lines, and does not generalize when rounding to different digits. At *attempt 3* the columns are no longer aligned.

How can I get the desired output using features that come with R?

### Desired output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  
foo some text 

    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  -2.069  -0.654  -0.092  -0.075   0.696   1.997 
      
    *additional information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this task you can use two function of base r consecutively. There is the function `capture.output` which captures the output of a command like print. Using `paste` to combine the desired number of spaces, it can be written to stdout with `writelines`, which preserves the line structure of the dataframe printout.
To do the above a combined all your information given in the printout as an example to a data.frame (df).

```
df = data.frame("Min."=-2.069, "First Qu."= -0.654,  "Median"= -0.092   , "Mean"  =-0.075, "Third Qu."=  0.696,    "Max."=  1.997 )
writeLines(paste0("  ", capture.output(print(df, row.names = F))))
```

I added roe.names = F, to suppress printing the row numbers of the dataframe

Comment: Great! `writeLines(paste0("   ", capture.output(print(s, row.names = F))))` was finally applicable to my special case.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I could come up with was to manually re-assemble the 'summary' output to account for the different 'cell' widths:

```
add_indent_and_right_align <- function(summry, indent=2, minDist= 2, rounding = 3) {
  # add an indent and then right-align summary output table
  #
  # summry - summary object
  # indent - integer Number of spaces to add before summary output
  # minDist . integer Minimal number of spaces between two columns
  # rounding - integer Number of decimals to round summary to

  header <- attr(summry, "names")
  value <- round(summry, 3)     
  r = list()
  for (i in seq_along(header)) {
    # find out how wide the column has to be
    # to fit header and value and indent (if first column) or minDist
    #
    max_len <- max(nchar(header[i]), nchar(value[i]))       
    if (i == 1) {
      cell_width <- max_len + indent
      r[1] <- paste0(paste0(rep(" ", cell_width - nchar(header[i])), collapse=""), header[i])
      r[2] <- paste0(paste0(rep(" ", cell_width - nchar(value[i])), collapse=""), value[i])
    } else {
      cell_width <- max_len + minDist
      r[1] <- paste0(r[1], paste0(rep(" ", cell_width - nchar(header[i])), collapse=""), header[i])
      r[2] <- paste0(r[2], paste0(rep(" ", cell_width - nchar(value[i])), collapse=""), value[i])
    }
  }
  return(paste0(r, collapse="\n"))
}

f <- function(x) {
  indent <- 4 # how many spaces shoud the whole summary output be indented?
  s <- summary.default(x)

  cat(paste0(rep("-", 70), collapse=""), "\n")
  cat("\n")
  cat("foo some text", "\n")
  cat("\n")
  cat(add_indent_and_right_align(summry=s, indent=4, minDist= 1, rounding = 3), "\n")
  cat("\n")
  cat(paste0(paste0(rep(" ", indent), collapse=""), "*additional information"), "\n")
  cat("\n")
}

set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)
f(x)
```

Returns:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
>
> foo some text
>
>     Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu.  Max.
>   -2.215  -0.494  0.114 0.109   0.692 2.402
>
>   *additional information
> ```

Comment: Nice hack, thanks! I chose the other answer, though, since it seems kind of the standard way.